# Смысл помещения DateTime в контейнер

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

В исходном  коде одной программы, внутри NinjectModule, я нашёл такую строку:

```
Bind<DateTime>().ToSelf()
```

Для чего в контейнер помещается тип DateTime? Чего хотел добиться автор? Не могу представить сценарий, когда это может пригодиться.

Comment: Не силен в ninject и не понимаю приведенный код, но если кто то оборачивает DateTime, это может быть для тестирумости, например. Но это чисто предположение

Comment: Хмм... а `DateTime` - это именно `System.DateTime`, не свой какой-то тип? Если встроенный, то смысл мне не ясен, тем более, что `kernel.Get<DateTime>()` в таком случае выбрасывает _Ninject.ActivationException_.

Comment: Так точно, используется System.DateTime.